# How to prevent show xml content in Chrome's devtool?

Tags: reactjs, xml, google-chrome, security, encryption

I got encrypted data from backend and decrytped this data in frontend(reactjs). Everything works fine but I can reach the data from google Develeoper Tools network section(shown in below).
These data can be `data:image/svg+xml;base64`,  `"data:image/jpeg;base64`,  `data:image/png;base64` formats and I need to prevent accessibility of real image from chrome since when I double clicked I am able to reach the image and encryption make no sense.

Is there any proper way to handle this problem?

[image: network section]

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not how it works. base64 is not encrypted, it's just an encoding. The data URI scheme is something that browsers understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme. If you want it to be encrypted, then encrypt the data instead of base64, but then you will need custom processing to decrypt on the front-end, which someone will be able to figure out and do.

Comment: After decryption I convert it to base64 format. So I have another logic for encrypt/decrypt. But If people can reach this base64 data why should I use encryption. That is why I was asking is there any way to prevent it.

Comment: Gotcha. You didn't post any code, so it is hard to tell from just the description and screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot both trust a client and not trust a client with data.

As long as the client code running in the browser has access to the unencrypted data to present or compute against it, the unencrypted data is subject to observation.

There neither is nor can be a fool-proof work-around.

Comment: One every 10 posts in the security section is asking to do the impossible. : )

Comment: So its mean that you never hide an image as long as browser render it. Is it same for the server side rendering?

Comment: Server-side rendering would allow the rendering method to be secured but obviously not the shared product of the rendering.

Comment: So in order to render encrypted image, I should decrypt and provide to browser to interpret. If browser can interpret client also copy the base64 format or whatever it is. There is no way to prevent this subject to observation.

Comment: Yes, a decrypted resource is no longer secured once it is decrypted for presentation.